# Element coordinates in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, coordinates

Say that I have an element inside a div (or any other containing element, or perhaps just in the body of the document). How do I get the (x,y) coordinates of that element, relative to its container?

And I need to be able to do it in pure Javascript...

Comment: jQuery is pure javascript. :D There's no interrupter like coffescript or server->bytecode->JavaScirpt hackery going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the below

```
document.getElementById("elementId").offsetTop;
document.getElementById("elementId").offsetLeft;
```

Answer (score 8):

The `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` properties are relative to `offsetParent` so you can get an element's position relative to its parent for free. If you want the position relative to the entire `body` then you need to traverse the `offsetParent` chain and sum the values.

The following function accomplishes this:

```
function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = 0, curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

Comment: Two issues with this code. First it leaks curtop into the global namespace. The var line should read "var curleft = 0, curtop = 0;". Second it returns nothing if the passed object has no offsetParent.

Comment: @Hans - Good call on the scope leakage. Fixed. As for the other issue, every element has an `offsetParent`. I would say that the result *should* be undefined for any passed object that doesn't have such a property. I've made that explicit.

Comment: I should have noted at the time that I first saw this technique used here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

Answer (score 0):

Going off of ShankarSangoli's post, it can be expanded this way. Get the difference between the parent (container) and the child (element in question):

```
var parentOffsetTop = document.getElementById("parentId").offsetTop;
var parentOffsetLeft = document.getElementById("parentId").offsetLeft;
var childOffsetTop = document.getElementById("childId").offsetTop;
var childOffsetLeft = document.getElementById("childId").offsetLeft;

var xOffset = parentOffsetLeft - childOffsetLeft;
var yOffset = parentOffsetTop - childOffsetTop;
```

EDIT: seems I was mistaken, offsetLeft and offsetTop are based off of the parent anyway. You do not need to do this manually!