# input type text - how to add a div below or above depending on its position in the web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a textfield in my page:

```
<input type='text' />
```

I have some logic that if something is typed a div will appear below. 
(The div is like a popup in a combo to give you an idea)

The problem is that if the textfield is at the bottom of the page I would rather the div would appear on the top of the textfield.

Is there an easy way to achieve this ?

Another way to phrase this is:

how do I know if adding a div at the bottom of another HTML element will not fit the current page ?

Comment: You would have to do some calculation; get the absolute position of the div popup, the height of the div popup and see if it is greater than the body height. If so, move it above the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the available space below the element and decide the position as required.

```
var popupTop = <offset-top-of-element> + element.offsetHeight;

if(window.offsetHeight - popupTop > 100) { // change 100 as needed
   // display below
}
else {
   // display above
}
```

For finding the offset top of the element, you will need to recursively add parent.offsetTop till there is no parent as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6780661/921204

*NOTE*: I haven't tested `window.offsetHeight` for cross-browser compliantness. You may need multi-browser code for the same. Other than that this will work across pretty much all the browsers.

Comment: will this solution work cross-browser ? this seems like a good idea

Comment: You will likely need to write multi-browser code for `window.offsetHeight`. Other than that this should work in pretty much all browsers.

Comment: can you edit your answer about the window.offsetHeight being crossbrowser... once done I think this will be the answer

Comment: I've edited the answer. BTW, if you are using jQuery there is a sure shot cross-browser way of doing this.

Answer (score -1):

You may look here http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/. From what you describe I guess you need a tooltip. This library will position your div automatically.

Comment: that's a good example of what I don't want. I just tried out if the textfield is at the bottom of the page the tool tip does not appear. It really sucks

Comment: Wow i have used this for a project last week and it works for me. There are properties with which you can manipulate the position. http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position - you can check this out.